# Firestore lecture operations count

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I would like to understand how Firestore works for counting read operations.

[firestore lecture operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXCvO.jpg)

I have a database and an application for mobile devices so to make Firestore go offline, nothing needs to be done.
When my application is opened the user receives data from a collection of | n | documents.

I wanted to understand if a user who opens the application with the internet will perform read operations from the database even if there are no changes in the database?
Or every time it accesses if there are no changes, no read operations are added since the data still resides in the cache?

Answer (score 1):

> if a user who opens the application with the internet on will perform read operations from the database even if there are no changes in the database?

If you are using `get()` call, the Firestore SDK will always try to get the data from the server, no matter if the data is changed or not. You'll be able to use the data from the cache, **only** if the device goes offline. However, if you trying to listen for changes in real-time using a `SnapShotListener`, according to the official documentation:

> The initial state can come from the server directly, or from a local cache. If there is a state available in a local cache, the query snapshot will be initially populated with the cached data, then updated with the server's data when the client has caught up with the server's state.

In other words, if the server says that you have no new added/updated/deleted documents, you get the data from the cache. However, there is something else you should take care regarding [the duration of time you can get the data from cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

[Another possible charge might also come from](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

But all these charges are normal according to how is Firestore designed.